# How to use authentication from my ASP.NET Core site to authenticate angular 2 web app?

Tags: authentication, cookies, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core app with angular 2 front-end. I use cookie auth.
But I want to split my app into 2 separate sites - one front-end site on angular2 and one back-end site on asp.net core.

How do I use auth from ASP.NET Core site to authenticate front-end app?
There's a login page in my back-end site. How do I identify in front-end app that I'm not authenticated, then redirect to back-end app and then get auth cookies? I'm not sure I understand mechanic of this process.

Comment: Maybe people knowing answers, would profit from displaying core code pieces for present solution and already present ideas - so is this cross domain or ...?

Comment: I don't think code is needed here. I use pretty standart cookie-based auth like in docs.asp.net example.

Comment: This won't be cross-domain for now. It's an intranet app with UI project being hosten on a Linux server, and backend will be on windows server for now (with migration on linux after getting rid of windows-specific libs). But ability to make it cross-domain would be definitely useful. I just need to understand in which direction I should look. I saw 1 example of single sign-on between multiple asp core apps on docs.asp.net, but my case is different, as frontend isn't asp.core app.

Comment: My experience with SSO is minor, but in every project I used it, we simply followed the prescriptions that special framework needed ... but long forgotten ;-)

Comment: try this https://github.com/openiddict

Comment: **update:** I've tested various options and my option of choice is angular2-jwt library from auth0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used token based authentication. I choosed this solution: https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core & https://github.com/nbarbettini/SimpleTokenProvider

Comment: Looks very promising. I'm in the middle of implementing this. Thanks!

Comment: How is it comparing to IdentityServer4 ? https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io this one mentioned in the Docs of asp,net core -> https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/

Answer (score 6):

For Authentication I prefer to use cookies.

[Use cookie authentication without Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x#persistent-cookies)

### Login Code

```cs
    [HttpPost("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<HttpBaseResult> Login([FromBody]LoginDto dto)
    {
        var user = db.Users.Include(u=>u.UserRoles).SingleOrDefault();
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName)
        };
        var roles = user.UserRoles.Select(u => u.Role);
        foreach (var item in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, item.Name));
        }
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
            new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
            new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = dto.RememberMe });
        // ...
    }
```

### Cross Domain

#### ConfigureServices

```cs
    {
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
        // Dynamically set the domain name of the prod env and dev env
        options.Cookie.Domain = Configuration["CookieDomain"];
    });
```

#### Configure

```cs
    app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "http://www.example.com","http://example.com")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());
```

### Angular Code

```js
    public login(userName: string, password: string, rememberMe: boolean): Observable<HttpBaseResult> {
      const url: string = `${this.url}/login`;
      var data = {
        UserName: userName,
        Password: password,
        RememberMe: rememberMe
      };
      return this.client.post<HttpBaseResult>(url, data, { withCredentials: true });
    }
```

Comment: And how do you send the cookies on subsequent requests?

Comment: Subsequent requests will be sent by the browser and the browser will automatically bring the cookies.